# Blocking concurrent queue with lock-free algorithms

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm building a blocking concurrent queues (i.e., consumers sleep if nothing in queue until waked up by producers). My use case is restricted in that the dequeue operation will *always* block on an empty queue; there is no `tryDequeue`.

My current implementation simply uses a `std::mutex` with a `std::condition_variable`. I'd like to know if it makes sense to improve the data structure with lock-free algorithms. In the case where the queue is empty, that probably doesn't make sense since the consumers have to block anyway. But in the case where the queue is non-empty, could there be anything I can do?

Comment: Why the vote to close?

Comment: You can't sensibly "block" in a lock-free fashion. (You could busy-loop, but that wouldn't be useful.)

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm thinking maybe when dequeueing, I can first lock-free-ly try to pop the front, and only when that doesn't work go on to the blocking stage? (Of course enqueueing would have to be changed correspondingly.)

Comment: @Kerrek, busy-loops (AKA spinlocks) _are_ often useful for this sort of purpose - i.e. when you expect other threads to "lock" the shared object for periods of time shorter than the cost incurred in a context switch to the kernel to do traditional blocking.

Comment: Most modern locks spin before switching context anyway; so you probably won't gain anything without a much more significant design change.

Comment: @GavinLock: A "blocking operation" is usually understood as something that results in a descheduling of the blocked thread so that the OS can do other work. Using a spin-lock to provide a blocking dequeue would probably be a very surprising implementation. In other words, spin-lock is useful to provide synchronization, but not blocking.

Comment: @Kerrek, we're not talking about consumers needing to block (for a potentially long time) until the queue becomes non-empty. Rather, using a spinlock to lock the queue just long enough to safely pop an item _if there is one available_. This is sometimes done with a single spinlock shared by both producers and consumers, but can also be done with one spinlock for producers and one for consumers (for example [Herb Sutter's Dr Dobbs article on this](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/measuring-parallel-performance-optimizin/212201163).)  Blocking on an empty queue is done with other synch objects.

Comment: P.S. I understand a "blocking operation" to be nothing more than an operation that has to stop and wait for something else - and a spinlock is one way to "block" _without having to deschedule the thread_, specifically used when the wait time is expected to be less than the time it takes to context switch to another thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is asking if you should go lock-free.

On modern systems lock-free makes sense only when the work time per item is substantially under a 1 ms, or some hilarious massive lock contention scenario (not discussed, web server is an example).

You can get a feel for the time it takes to notify a condition variable by looking at the time it takes a condition variable to respond:

```
#include <thread>
#include <array>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>

std::chrono::microseconds timestamp()
{
    const auto microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
    return microseconds;
}
struct measurement
{
    std::chrono::microseconds sent, acknowledged, received;
    measurement() :sent{ 0 }, acknowledged{ 0 }, received{ 0 } {}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::array<measurement, 15> notifications;
    std::mutex notifications_m;
    std::condition_variable notification_cv;
    auto notifying_thread = std::thread([&] {
        for (auto i = 0; i < notifications.size(); ++i)
        {
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(notifications_m);
                notifications[i].sent = timestamp();
            }
            notification_cv.notify_one();
            //Now we wait for the notification to be acknowledged
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(notifications_m);
            const auto check_that_acknowledged = [&] {return notifications[i].acknowledged != std::chrono::microseconds(0); };
            notification_cv.wait(lk, check_that_acknowledged);
            notifications[i].received = timestamp();

        }
    });
    for (auto i = 0; i < notifications.size(); ++i)
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(notifications_m);
            const auto check_that_sent = [&] {return notifications[i].sent != std::chrono::microseconds(0); };
            notification_cv.wait(lk, check_that_sent);
            notifications[i].acknowledged = timestamp();
        }
        notification_cv.notify_one();
    }
    notifying_thread.join();
    //
    for (const auto& notification : notifications)
    {
        const auto difference_us = notification.received - notification.sent;
        std::cout << difference_us.count() << " microseconds" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Even on some of the highest latency systems, a round trip takes around 0.1ms:
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9598c83dd05e09b5